# how to connect another database from magento

Tags: magento-1.7, module, database

Is it possible to connect to another database from Magento and accessing data?

If I need to create a module, how can I create a module to access another database? Is there any tutorial which tells about the same from scratch?
Any Idea?

Answer (score 20):

First thing you need to do is create a connection in your module's config.xml. It should look similar to the `default_setup` in your `/app/etc/local.xml`. Here you can specify the host to be localhost and then set a different dbname or you can specify a different host completely. I have also used a socket before which works also.

```
<resources>
    <new_db>
        <connection>
            <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
            <username><![CDATA[db_username]]></username>
            <password><![CDATA[db_password]]></password>
            <dbname><![CDATA[db_name]]></dbname>
            <model>mysql4</model>
            <type>pdo_mysql</type>
            <active>1</active>
        </connection>
    </new_db>
</resources>
```

Now after this you will be able to connect to this database an perform queries as follows:

```
$new_db_resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$connection = $new_db_resource->getConnection('new_db');
$results    = $connection->query('SELECT * FROM table');
```

If you want to do this via a model then you can specify the `read`, `write` and `setup` resources as follows. This will again be done inside the `resources` node in your config.xml and you should replace `test` with what your model has been setup as.

```
<resources>
    <new_db>
        <connection>
            <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
            <username><![CDATA[db_username]]></username>
            <password><![CDATA[db_password]]></password>
            <dbname><![CDATA[db_name]]></dbname>
            <model>mysql4</model>
            <type>pdo_mysql</type>
            <active>1</active>
        </connection>
    </new_db>
    <test_write>
        <connection>
            <use>new_db</use>
        </connection>
    </test_write>
    <test_read>
        <connection>
            <use>new_db</use>
        </connection>
    </test_read>
    <test_setup>
        <connection>
            <use>new_db</use>
        </connection>
    </test_setup>
</resources>
<models>
    <test>
        <class>My_Test_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>test_resource</resourceModel>
    </test>
    <test_resource>
        <class>My_Test_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <test>
                <table>test</table>
            </test>
        </entities>
    </test_resource>
</models>
```

The model itself will try to find it's connection information in the function `getConnection` `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php`. If you log the `$name` passed in you will see values like `poll_write`, `tag_write` and `cms_read` where the first part matches the models section in the config.xml, in our case you would see `test_write`, `test_read` or `test_setup`. If it cannot find a connection matching this then it will use the default connections `core_read`, `core_write` or `core_setup`

Comment: sorry,It does not work for me.

Comment: I don't understand where to write this code,where to perform query and what to chage in this.for example wether i type <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>  or <host>localhost</host> etc.

Comment: @bab are you wanting to make a single query or a model that works with another database?

Comment: I am making a single query  but if possible through model also.Actually i am working on a survey site . i want to access databse of this site through magento.I read so many articles for the same but i have no idea where to put this code .If possible please tell me what changes i can make in your coding to get desired result.Thanks.

Comment: @bab the second config.xml example should work for the model. did you get any errors with the code?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config> 
<modules>
  <SmashingMagazine_LogProductUpdate>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
       </SmashingMagazine_LogProductUpdate>
    </modules>
 <global>

Comment: My config.xml is  <config><modules>
<SmashingMagazine_LogProductUpdate>
<version>0.0.1</version>
 </SmashingMagazine_LogProductUpdate>
    </modules><global><resources><new_db>
        <connection>
            <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
            <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
       <password><![CDATA[]]></password>
            <dbname><![CDATA[survey]]></dbname>
            <model>mysql4</model>
            <type>pdo_mysql</type>
            <active>1</active>
        </connection>
    </new_db>

Comment: <test_write><connection><use>new_db</use></connection>   </test_write><test_read><connection><use>new_db</use>
</connection></test_read><test_setup><connection>          <use>new_db</use></connection></test_setup></resources><models><test>      <class>SmashingMagazine_LogProductUpdate_Model</class>
<resourceModel>LogProductUpdate_resource</resourceModel>
</test><test_resource><class>SmashingMagazine_LogProductUpdate_Model_Resource</class><entities><test><table>users</table></test></entities>
</test_resource></models></global></config>

Comment: I have a little knowledge of xml code.please tell me where is the problem and what will be the controller file for this(Is controller is necessary for it or not?) I type the sql query in header.phtml(IS this file is the right place for query?) I have an error Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 933266064 I can't understand this.

Comment: Is there similar solution for M2 without editing `env.php`. DB configuration should be done inside the module itself like this.

Answer (score 3):

After reading all these answers,searching and making some test i found this solution. Here is my blog where I wrote the [solution](http://abelbolanos.blogspot.com/2016/05/magento-multiple-database-connection.html).

Working with Magento 1.9 I was asked to make multiple read and write connections. 
Magento has the possibility to configure read and write connections in the /etc/local.xml. Just set the tag use to let Magento know which one is available.

```
<default_setup>
    <connection>
        <!-- LOCALHOST -->
        <host>localhost</host>
        <username>root</username>               
        <password>123456</password>
        <dbname>magento_db</dbname>
        <initstatements>SET NAMES utf8</initstatements>
        <model>mysql4</model>
        <type>pdo_mysql</type>
        <pdotype></pdotype>
        <active>1</active>
    </connection>
</default_setup>
<default_read>
    <connection>
        <use/>
        <!-- ANOTHER SERVER -->
        <host>other_server</host>
        <username>root</username>               
        <password>123456</password>
        <dbname>magento_db</dbname>
        <initstatements>SET NAMES utf8</initstatements>
        <model>mysql4</model>
        <type>pdo_mysql</type>
        <pdotype></pdotype>
        <active>1</active>
        </use></connection>
</default_read>
<default_write>
    <connection>
        <use/>
        <!-- LOCALHOST -->
        <host>localhost</host>
        <username>root</username>               
        <password>123456</password>
        <dbname>magento_db</dbname>
        <initstatements>SET NAMES utf8</initstatements>
        <model>mysql4</model>
        <type>pdo_mysql</type>
        <pdotype></pdotype>
        <active>1</active>
        </use></connection>
</default_write>
```

We can define n connections in the same config file like this test example

```
<test_read>
 <connection>
   <!-- TEST SERVER -->
   <host>test_server</host>
   <username>root</username>
   <password>123456</password>
   <dbname>magento_db</dbname>
   <initstatements>SET NAMES utf8</initstatements>
   <model>mysql4</model>
   <type>pdo_mysql</type>
   <pdotype></pdotype>
   <active>1</active>
 </connection>
</test_read>
```

The limit is that the connections are applied to the whole system but my idea is to set only for certain resources. 
In this case I have a custom report module where I only want to make read connections in the Order table. 
After overriding the Order resource Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order.php 
Just make 3 updates

1. Make a flag to know if its time to change the connection
   $reportConnection.
2. Update function _construct() to create the custom connection and add
   it to the array of resources.
3. Update function _getConnection() to decide if use the custom
   connection.

```
//flag
public $reportConnection = false;

/**
*Just add the connection defined in the local.xml 'test_read'
*/
protected function _construct(){
    $this->_init('sales/order', 'entity_id');
    $this->_resources->getConnection('test_read');
}

/**
*Make the connection if the flag is set
*/
protected function _getConnection($connectionName){
 if (isset($this->_connections[$connectionName])) {
   return $this->_connections[$connectionName];
    }

   if($connectionName == 'read' && $this->reportConnection)
        $this->_connections[$connectionName] = $this->_resources->getConnection('test_read');
   else{
   if (!empty($this->_resourcePrefix)) {
      $this->_connections[$connectionName] = $this->_resources->getConnection(
      $this->_resourcePrefix . '_' . $connectionName);
  } else {
   $this->_connections[$connectionName] = $this->_resources->getConnection($connectionName);
  }
   }
   return $this->_connections[$connectionName];
}
```

Last step is to make call an Order collection but using the test_read connection.

```
//Get the Order model
$model = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
//set the flag
$model->getResource()->reportConnection = true;
//get the collection
$collection = $model->getCollection();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your module etc/config.xml add following code:

```
<global>
    <resources>
        <modulename_write>
            <connection>
                <use>modulename_database</use>
            </connection>
        </modulename_write>
        <modulename_read>
            <connection>
                <use>modulename_database</use>
            </connection>
        </modulename_read>
        <modulename_setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </modulename_setup>
        <modulename_database>
            <connection>
                <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[db_username]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[db_password]]></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[tablename]]></dbname>
                <model>mysql4</model>
                <type>pdo_mysql</type>
                <active>1</active>
            </connection>
        </modulename_database>
    </resources>
</global>
```

To get data from table using new database:

```
<?php 
    $resource   = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $conn       = $resource->getConnection('modulename_read');
    $results    = $conn->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM tablename');

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($results);
?>
```