# Instantiate Mage.app to connect to remote install inside local install

Tags: database, migration, magento-1.4

I am working on migrating an old 1.4 site. Part of this migration is building a feature that moves tons of product information into a dedicated "product library" module (a custom entity not related to products).

The API is pretty restricting in 1.4 as there are a number of calls I can do to pull information, but they each require a handful of SOAP requests for each "product". This is incredibly slow.

What I am hoping to try (or at least explore to see if it will be worth it) is to instantiate a different instance of Mage.app inside my module's controller/helper/etc that would connect to the remote store's database directly so that I would be able to call the collections myself.

I am thinking it would be something such as:

```
<?php
// inside my local install module's controller or helper or wherever I decide to place it
$remote = new Mage;

// Load different local.xml config???
$remote->setConfig('...path to custom local.xml?');
$remote->setStore(1);
$remote->getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
// Do things with my collection ...
```

**How can I connect to a remote install of Magento using a different configuration from within a local development install?**

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the bottom lines of your code, the thing you want to do is get the product collection and do stuff with that collection.

Getting an external script to run Magento isn't that hard, but you never do a `new Mage`. Your code should be like this:

```
<?php
// First of all, include Mage.php (make sure the path is correct)
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);

// Initialise Magento
Mage::app('default');

/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection $collection */
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

// Do whatever you want with the collection
```

With the code above you can do almost any Magento action you want. After doing a `Mage::app()` you will be able to use stuff like `Mage::getModel()`, `Mage::helper()`, etc.

Comment: The point of instantiating `new Mage()` object is so that I can load a different configuration so I can connect to a different Magento install on another server. Basically, I want to use Magento's ORM style collection methods on a collection stored in another remote Magento install.

Comment: What would be the reason to get different configuration? I'd suggest you use the Magento API (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html) if you just want to get data from that other Magento instance. That way, you can just get a list of products and work with them.

Comment: Well, if it used the same configuration, it wouldn't connect to a different store. The API is not an option as I explained in the question.

Comment: I think this might be the answer you're looking for: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10497/how-to-connect-another-database-from-magento. You can connect to a different database.