# Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, database, sql

I created login form. but I got this error. how can I solve this error.
[image]

Comment: I am guessing you are using mysql_connect in your `login.php` file line number `6`.

Comment: Please change the code and use PHP PDO classes instead

Comment: You can refer the following link for more details https://www.sitepoint.com/migrate-from-the-mysql-extension-to-pdo/

Comment: why you have added tag for magento ?

Comment: do not use core php function directly in framework for db operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For custom queries magento has `core_read` and `core_write` resources use that one

Example of how to use `core_read`

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql        = "Select * from catalog_product_flat_1";
$rows       = $connection->fetchAll($sql); //fetchRow($sql), fetchOne($sql),...
Zend_Debug::dump($rows);
```

For `core_write` use below code

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$table = $resource->getTableName('catalog/product');
$query = "UPDATE {$table} SET {item} = '{value}' WHERE entity_id = 'value'";
$writeConnection->query($query);`
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `mysql`, `mysqli` or even PDO in Magento code.

If this is the Magento database, use the existing connection from Magento

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792762/how-to-do-custom-query-in-magento

If it is a different database, you still can use the Magento methods, but need to define an additional connection as explained here: [how to connect another database from magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10497/how-to-connect-another-database-from-magento)